# how to get an added attribute in a formdata

Tags: javascript, form-data

While trying to check a value adding in FormData object whenever I returned values are "undefined".

```
    f = new FormData();

    f.append('name', 'Wallace Maxters');

    f.append('image', $('#file').prop('files')[0]);

    // trying to get added attributes

    f.toString() //"[object FormData]"

    console.log(f['name']) // undefined
```

I tried to use the `get` described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get), but this function only exists in newest browsers .

How do I get a value added in the `FormData`?

Comment: The documentation from MDN claims there are more methods available than `append`. I've never heard of that, and I can't get any of them working in Chrome, and even when iterating over the available keys, [all I get is `append`](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/3p06g43m/), so I'm thinking the MDN docs are wrong, there is no such thing, at least in Chrome, as a `get()` method